# How to break a while, when subtracting the new value from a variable from the previous one?

Tags: python, while-loop, break

How to break a while, when subtracting the new value from a variable from the previous one?

The code is:

```
Calc = (PTO2.h - coefficients[1]) / coefficients[0]
while True:
    NewP = IAPWS97(P=PH5, s=Calc)
    Calc = (NewP.h - coefficients[1]) / coefficients[0]
    print(NewP.h)
```

The results are the following:

```
3181.2423174700475, 3125.5329929699737, 3145.170908432667, 
3138.216970209225, 3140.675480138904, 3139.805801319479,
3140.1133819014494, 3140.0045917261796, 3140.043069467109, 
3140.029460245017, 3140.034273686281, 3140.032571219946,
3140.033173365131
```

The idea is to stop when the value does not increase anymore ie, 3140 it should be the final value.
This problem could be solved with 5 or 6 iterations.

Comment: It's spelled "break", not "brake", and Python has a keyword with exactly this name for this purpose.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please check if this meets your requirements:

```
# Define required difference
difference = 0.1
solutions = []

# Add 1st solution or guess
# func is whatever function you are using, with the required arguments, arg.
solutions.append(func(arg))
delta = soltutions[-1]

# Check if delta is still positive and if the delta meets the requirements
while delta > 0 and delta > difference:
   solutions.append(func(arg))
   delta = solutions[-2] - solutions[-1]

print(f'Final result is: {solutions[-1]}')
```

This solution supposes that you want to finish execution if the variation starts to go negative. If the sign doesn't matter, you can use `abs()` in `delta`.